# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre publicar en sistemas de archivo y web deploy en asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Podrian explicarme la diferencia entre  publicar en sistemas de archivos y web deploy en asp.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Resumiendo:

1. Web Deploy - Si tienes un IIS en un servidor corriendo y configurado para recibir solicitudes de Despliegues Web, enviará todos los archivos solicitados por el IIS. El IIS empezará inmediatamente a correr la nueva página.
2. Web Deploy Package - Si tienes un IIS en tu servidor corriendo y configurado para recibir Empaquetados Web Deploy, empaquetará toda tu página web y la subirá al servidor. El IIS empezará inmediatamente a correr la nueva página.
3. FTP subirá todos los archivos al servidor FTP (puede ser cualquier SO que pueda manejar FTP), pero ten en cuenta que esto NO es seguro y que el proceso entero de subida puede ser capturado y comprometido.
4. Sistema de Archivos enviará todos los archivos requeridos para lanzar el servicio web, por cualquier método soportado por el proyecto actual, al directorio que le proporciones en tu máquina.

<sub>Traducción de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660168/579895)</sub>

Comment: El web debploy entonces es un compilado dll las que se suben y el sistema de archivos es la carpeta completa asi lo entiendo favor corrijanme si entendi mal

Comment: @lucho No es exacto. Web deploy tiene varias ventajas, por ejemplo solo debe subir los archivos que han cambiado, y el IIS solo se reinicia cuando todos los archivos han subido.

Comment: @lucho Si quieres algo mas de información, puedes mirar la sección Features en [esta web](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy) (En inglés, he tratado de buscar documentación en español y no he encontrado nada interesante)

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh revisare la documentacion de la web